# Not able to insert value into database on django form submit

Tags: django, django-forms

I have created a form that takes 2 inputs from a user and I want to add current date-time and currently logged in user when I receive user inputs in the POST method.

Help me to write a view to edit the form. In the below code I am not able to assign value to blog_author.

models.py (I am accepting blog_name and blog_details from user)

```
class blogs(models.Model):
    blog_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=False,null=False)
    blog_details = models.TextField(blank=False,null=False)
    blog_author = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True,null=True)
    blog_created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

forms.py #with only two fields

```
class blogForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = blogs
        fields = ('blog_name','blog_details')
```

views.py #validation of form

```
def create_blog(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = blogForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=False)
            form.cleaned_data['blog_author'] = request.user
            form.save()   
    form = blogForm()
    context = {"form":form}
    return render(request,'create_blog.html',context)
```

Comment: `blog_author` should be a ForeignKey to the User model, not a CharField.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is in this line:

`form.cleaned_data['blog_author'] = request.user` returns a `User` object.

However,

`blog_author = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True,null=True)`

is a `CharField`.

You either must change `blog_author` to a ForeignKey if you wish to save the `User` instance or you must replace `request.user` with `request.user.username`, which returns a string of the username of the user which can go in your CharField.

Full code with the `request.user.username option` :

```
def create_blog(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = blogForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=False)
            form.cleaned_data['blog_author'] = request.user.username
            form.save()   
    form = blogForm()
    context = {"form":form}
    return render(request,'create_blog.html',context)
```

**Edit based on chat**

```
def create_blog(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = blogForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            blog = form.save()
            blog.refresh_from_db()
            blog.blog_author= request.user.get_username()
            blog.save()   
    form = blogForm()
    context = {"form":form}
    return render(request,'create_blog.html',context)
```

Comment: Which method did you try?

Comment: Did you create a custom user model?

Comment: I have changed the request.user to request.user.username, I have not created any model apart from the model mentioned in the question

Comment: try this: request.user.get_username(). It is an alternative method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200384/discussion-between-matthew-gaiser-and-amol-rane).